# Proof that matrices A(BX) and X have same reduced echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Given**
>
> $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\\ a & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B =
>  \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ with a $\in \mathbb R$ and $X \in M_{23}(\mathbb
>  F)$
>
> Proof that A(BX) and X have the same reduced echelon form.

Would you please guide me a little bit with this? I tried playing around with it a little bit and I think A(BX) = (AB)X might be a good start but I'm stuck :(

**Current approach**

Let $X'$ be the reduced echelon form of $X$ and $[A(BX)]'$ the reduced echelon form of $A(BX)$.

$X' = [A(BX)]' \Leftrightarrow X $ and $A(BX)$ are row equivalent. (found that in the script)

$A(BX) = (AB)X$

Now we show that (AB) is composed of elementary matrices.

$AB = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\\ 2a & 3\end{pmatrix} = 2\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} + 2a\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}+3\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$

Hence, $A(BX)$ and $X$ are row equivalent $\Rightarrow X' = [A(BX)]'$

$\Box$

What do you think?

Comment: Do you know the fact that row-equivalent matrices have the same reduced row echelon form?

Comment: Your argument is mostly correct, but you got confused between two different meanings of "elementary matrices" (and "composed"). You want to prove that $AB$ is a **product** of **the kind of elementary matrices that stand for row operations**, not a sum of the kind of elementary matrices that have a $1$ in one entry and $0$s everywhere else. And this is really easy to prove :)

Answer (score 1):

The most important fact is that

> Two $n\times m$ matrices $M$ and $N$ are row-equivalent if and only if there exists an invertible $m\times m$ matrix $E$ such that $M=EN$.

Indeed, every row operation can be realized as the multiplication by a suitable invertible matrix. Thus, if $M_0$ is the reduced row echelon forms of $M$, there exists an invertible matrix $E$ such that $M_0=EM$. Similarly $N_0=FN$. If, additionally, $M_0=N_0$, we have
$$
EM=FN
$$
so $M=(E^{-1}F)N$.

Conversely, the reduced row echelon form of an invertible matrix $E$ is the identity, so $E$ is the product of matrices corresponding to elementary row operations. Therefore if $M=EN$, then $M$ and $N$ are row-equivalent.

In your case $A$ and $B$ *are* invertible, so from $ABX=(AB)X$ we get that $M=ABX$ and $N=X$ are row-equivalent, so they have the same reduced row echelon form.